# Rails after_save send mail with updated columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am stuck in an issue, wherein I would like to send mail after the after_save callback in rails.

Below is my code snippet:

```
class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :pending_with

protected
  def pending_with
    self.approver = self.mapping.user
  end
end

class ResponsesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @response = current_user.responses.new(response_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @response.save
        flash[:notice] = "Response has been saved successfully."
        Notification.confirm_approver(@response).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to dashboard_home_url }
      else
        flash[:error] = "There is some problem while saving the responses. Please try again."
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
      end
    end
  end
end

class Notification < ApplicationMailer
  def confirm_approver(response)
    @response = response
    p "============"
    p @response.approver.email.inspect
  end
end
```

My issue is that, I am not getting approver. Getting error:

```
undefined method `approver' for nil:NilClass
```

When I checked the record in the database, apporver ('id') is successfully saved. Am I missing anything here?

BACKTRACE:

```
app/mailers/notification.rb:11:in `confirm_approver'
vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1actionmailer (4.1.8) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:580:in `block in process'
vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1actionmailer (4.1.8) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:577:in `process'
vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1actionmailer (4.1.8) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:568:in `initialize'
vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1actionmailer (4.1.8) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:551:in `new'
vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1actionmailer (4.1.8) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:551:in `method_missing'
app/controllers/responses_controller.rb:23:in `block in create'
vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:433:in `call'
vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:433:in `retrieve_collector_from_mimes'
vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:256:in `respond_to'
app/controllers/responses_controller.rb:19:in `create'
```

Comment: Ok, there's not problem with the code you've pasted. On the other hand, trying to evaluate `@non_existing` will not trigger an undefined error like a local variable, but will return nil instead. Can you confirm with a search and hilight there is no typo on line passing it to `Notification.confirm_approver` and in `#confirm_approver` itself ?

Comment: Does it work if you call `@response.reload` after the call to `@response.save`?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Based on @zwippie inputs, it worked. Just made little modification to it.

```
def create
  @response = current_user.responses.new(response_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @response.save && @response.reload
      Notification.confirm_approver(@response).deliver
      flash[:notice] = "Response has been created successfully."
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
    end
  end
end
```